# Linker error referring to _main when running iOS unit test in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6, xctest

I'm trying to run a unit test in Xcode which links against a static library.  This static library "libGSG" includes static libraries from other 3rd party providers.  In one of them it seems they have a declaration of "main" that the linker is complaining about...

[image]

Is there anyone I can work around this or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 1):

Best I can suggest is trying to untangle your tests from the static library, so you don't need to link against it in your test target.

Comment: Actually yeah that works well enough thanks.  A bit of an inconvenience but I can work with this.